# Symfony 3 handling errors

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

Is there a way to handle all errors, from my symfony controllers, for example, if I get this error:

[image]

In my controller is there a way using try/catch to get this error?. For example:

```
class SomeClass extends Controller
{
    public function doSomethingAction(Request $request){
        //do something
        try {
            //do something
        }
        catch(\Exception $e){
            dump("ERROR:".$e->getMessage()); //<--this is not dumping anithing
        }
    }
}
```

I get allways the red screen message in the network call preview:
[image]

Instead of something like:

"ERROR: Type error: Argument 1 passed to.....

Comment: You are not giving us enough input. Are you sure the `//do something` are what causes your exception and not a dependency injection or an erroneous `ParamConverter` value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With PHP 7 you are able to handle PHP errors like TypeErrors from mismatching types (like in your example) as well as exceptions by catching their shared interface `Throwable`.

You should be careful with this, especially outside controllers, as this could prevent you from seeing unexpected errors which can lead to problems down the line or you not seeing when parts of your application are entirely broken. At the very least you should have proper logging in place.

In summary, you can catch errors along with exception like this:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (\Throwable $error) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: That's what I first wondered. [But `FatalThrowableError` extends `FatalErrorException` that extends `\ErrorException` in Symfony](https://github.com/symfony/debug/blob/master/Exception/FatalErrorException.php). And `\ErrorException` really is an exception and not an `\Error`, so the OP catch should do.

Comment: The FatalThrowableError is used by Symfony's DebugHandler to wrap php errors e.g. to uniformly deal with errors & exceptions inside the exception listener. Inside the form this should still be a regular `\TypeError` which means it's a `\Throwable`. See https://github.com/symfony/debug/blob/master/ErrorHandler.php#L645 (the method itself is used inside `register()` for `\register_shutdown_function()`)

Comment: Right, I got fooled by the fact that we only see the beginning of the stack trace

Comment: Could worth a recommendation to catch `\TypeError` rather than `\Throwable` then, to narrow it down and not catch everything as you perfectly pointed it

Comment: Yes, that would work too and in most cases I would suggest doing that to prevent the issues, i.e. unknowingly suppressing errors, I mentioned in my answer. I just understood the question to be, how to catch as broadly as possible, that's why I used Throwable instead.

Comment: Perfect,that's what I wanted. The point is that in some places I want to catch the possible errors, the error in the example I posted is forced by me to test the try catch statement. Thanks for the help